# How can a Windows based DHCP server update DNS Server on Linux?

Tags: dns, dhcp

The updates to the zone is protected by the key (similar to: allow-update { key "rndc-key"; }).

Comment: Not to get your hopes down, but i don't think that is possible... Why not just use dhcpd on Linux?

Comment: I use dhcpd at home. I heard that at work some DHCP servers were added and they are Windows based. I don't know how they implemented security. Could they have used certificates instead of keys?

Comment: afaik DHCP servers have no keys or certificates, security has got nothing to do with weather you can get an IP address or not. Most access-points/routers have the possibility not to use the internal DHCP server.

Comment: You can use IP based access control (allow the dhcp server to update), or you can use a Windows DNS server (using GSSAPI access control).

Comment: Does this question need to be clarified or is there actually an answer contained in the comments?

Comment: I think this question belongs to ServerFault, as it involves knowledge of both the Windows and the Linux side.

Comment: @Source Lab: The security in question was about DHCP server being able to update the DNS that is secured.

Comment: @moberley: I could not find an answer in the comments. As @Riccardo Murri said, it may be a ServerFault question.

Comment: There seems to be enough people that think this belongs on SF, so I'm going to close as OT. We [can't migrate there](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136/migrating-to-other-se-sites/137#137) until we're out of beta though

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP server never updates the DNS server anyway, at least for ones I've used.   What happens is that the DHCP *client* obtains the IP address (and potentially hostname) from the DHCP server and then *itself* tries to update the DNS server.

Comment: I am not sure that is the case. Allowing clients to update the DNS zone directly would be a security nightmare. A rogue client can wreck havoc on the network if it is allowed to update the DNS zones. When I setup the DNS on Linux, I setup who can update the zone and then I have to setup the DHCP with that same information. Here is what Windows does: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787034(WS.10).aspx. Here is a question at ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/34553/dhcp-failing-to-update-dns.